# Volume integral over circle not around the origin

Tags: integration, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

For an assignment I am asked to find the volume of a given volume R, namely
$R=\left\{(x,y,z):0\leq z\leq\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2},(x-1)^2+y^2\leq1\right\}$.

I have attempted solving this using cylindrical coördinates, which I believe is the way to go, but I don't quite understand the volume transformation.

For solving the volume I have tried solving
$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos{\varphi}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\,dz\,dr\,d\varphi$, but this gives the wrong answer (it results in $\frac{8}{3}\pi$ whereas it should be $\frac{8}{3}\pi-\frac{32}{9}$).

Integrating with respect to $\varphi$ from $0$ to $\pi$ however yields the correct result. This seems odd to me as the circle in the $xy$ plane over which we integrate the function is in the domain $\varphi=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

How come the $\varphi$ integration bounds are $0$ and $\pi$?

Comment: Oh yeah, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{2\cos{\varphi}}r\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} dz dr d\varphi=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{2\cos{\varphi}}r\sqrt{4-r^2}  dr d\varphi\\=
\frac{8}{3}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(1-|\sin(\varphi)|^3) d\varphi
=\frac{8}{3}\pi-\frac{32}{9}.$$
Have you considered the modulus at the last step?

Comment: Yeah you are correct, the modulus is the part I forgot. Interesting to see though is how an online tool also misses this [link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint_%7B-%5Cfrac%7Bpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2cos%5Cleft(p%5Cright)%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bsqrt%5Cleft(4-r%5E2%5Cright)%7D%20rdzdrdp)